# Blocking/disabling JavaFX 2 WebView LEFT click

Tags: webview, javafx

I have searched the web but can't get any information about this. 
There is a lot of information about disabling right click***, but how to disable left click?

***example:

```
WebView webview = new WebView();
webview.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer - Blocking/disabling LEFT and right click:

```
stage.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY ||
                        event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) { 
                event.consume();
            } 
        }
});
```