# JavaFX WebView prevent redirects

Tags: java, javafx

I have a webview loaded a URL, and I want to user dont be able to redirect from there, when they click in a link, "a href", it should just ignores it.
Already tried every single listener on the webengine, and nothing seems to work.

Tried with the DOM hook, but it doesnt seems to work, also tried this code:

```
sectionWebView3.getEngine().locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
               @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> prop, final String before, final String after) {
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                         @Override public void run() {
                              WebEngine vEngine = sectionWebView3.getEngine();
                              if (after == null || vEngine.getLocation().contains("editor.html")) {
                                   //System.out.println("BrowserPane.ChangeListener cancelling " + vEngine.getLocation());
                                   vEngine.getLoadWorker().cancel();
                              }  
                         }  
                    });
               }
          });
```

the cancel(); get called, but doesnt work, it just keeps loading...

Comment: Can you show us some code on what you have tried? What version of JavaFX are you using?

Comment: As a workaround, you may want to try disabling left or right clicks on the webview. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22264218/5250273

Comment: I dont wanr to disable all clicks, there is buttons that should work. And for the source I tried the javascript evebt hook, but the user will be able to write so I cabt hook a vlick before the element is created

Answer (score 0):

You might try to wait for the load finished event, and then get the document from the WebEngine by calling `sectionWebview3.getEngine().getDocument()`. Once you have this, get all the anchor tags by calling `doc.getElementsByTagName('a')`.

Once you have that list, you can iterate over it and set the href attribute of the anchor nodes to "#".

Comment: The problem is that Im loading an editor, tinymce, so the user can add more a tags